# Is there way to crop the output of a camera for a video chat?

Tags: video, camera, webcam, zoom.app

I'd like to use Zoom, Google Meet, etc. with my built in camera, or an external webcam.
However, the camera is too wide and shows parts of my setup that I'd prefer it not to. Is it possible to crop the view, which is then automatically used by video conferencing software? (ideally set once and forget)

For those wondering, I noticed this initially when I saw that Photo Booth crops my webcam input (which is embarrassing if you use that to judge what is in view!).

Comment: You could create your own mask and place it over the eye of the camera. If you have a hole punch to make a small enough circular mask, or cut a slot in an index card with an x-acto knife, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, only with a **virtual** *webcam*.

I recommend for simplicity [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) and preferably their **built-in** virt. webc. or *specifically* this plug-in [virtual webcam plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/). It goes like:

real webcam **->** O.B.S. **->** virtual webcam **->** meeting ( zoom, g meet, etc )

It would appear that you had 2 webcams to your meeting conferencing software, so you should pick the virtual one. At the same time, inside OBS you could crop the image or even apply some other fancy filters on it.

Comment: OBS is awesome because it does a LOT more, too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iGlasses](https://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/) software to achieve the cropping of your current video camera output.

Comment: To my experience iGlasses work perfectly for this purpose

Answer (score -1):

Cameras either have or don't have these features.

- **Pan** (side to side adjustment),
- **Tilt** (crop & enlarge),
- or **Zoom** (up & down adjustment)

This is shown as P/T/Z or PTZ on feature lists.
Apple's built in FaceTime camera has none of these sadly, you will have to look at the specs for any external camera you have to see if it does.

While there is some 3rd party apps that apply these after the fact, they do it by taking the video feed, adjusting it and pushing out a new virtual feed.
Since these will likely be suggested, be aware, these can be problematic. They can be buggy, they often ask for very deep control/access of your system, and some programs do not take virtual video input well. This is reflected in their universally poor ratings in the App Store. I have also found they are stubborn to uninstall and run insidiously in the background, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Can I ask for some clarification? I'm newish here and do not understand why my answer to the post got downvoted? Was it technically incorrect? Another reason? Am I misunderstanding some site etiquette and if so can someone fill me in, here or privately?

Comment: Actually you can use software like iGlasses, mentioned here, to zoom in or crop out video output. I’m sure other but similar software exists as well. Virtual panning, however will be limited to the outer reach of the uncropped view.